# How to map nested comments in react js?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I have the algorithm figured out by using the bfs algorithm but I don't know how to map each of the values

for example

The algorithm to traverse this in order is below (i tested this)

```
for (var responses of allcomm) {
  // insert a parent comment div with values here

  for (var comment of comment) {
    // insert a new ul div then the comment div here

    if (comment.responses.length !== 0) {
      
    }
  }
}
```

I'm very unfamiliar with the map and I cant figure out how to use the above algorithm to map properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking is how to render a tree of nested comments. For that, you're going to need recursion.

So, you'll want a component that can generate comments and then also nest its children. Something like,

```
const Responses = ({ responses }) =>
    <ul>
        // map all of the responses to a <li>
        {responses.map(({ detail, responses}) => 
           // print the detail and then list the responses below it
           // by recursively creating new Response components, i.e.,
           // nesting lists like so, ul > li > ul > li 
           <li>{detail}<Responses responses={responses} /></li>
        )}
    </ul>
```

You'll want to add css to indent each one within the parent and all that, but that's how you would generate a tree of components with simple recursion.

Is this what you're looking for. I didn't test this code, so it may not work out of the box. This is the general idea, though.

I didn't use your exact mark-up in the comments b/c it wasn't quite clear to me what you wanted to do, so swap in whatever elements you want to use. For a list of things, I tend to use lists, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to render an array in a **Reactjs** , just do this :

```
const Responses = ({ responses }) =>{
             <ul> 
                  {responses.map(response =>
                        return (<Responses response={response} />
                  )}
              </ul>
  }
```